# In django-treebeard, how to add child for sibling

Tags: django-treebeard

In my project , i should use tree structure.
after seeing documentation of treebeard ,i thought it is well suitable.
thanks for providing clear documentation.
In [documentation](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), provided the example

```py
    node = get(root.pk).add_child(name='Memory')
    
    get(node.pk).add_sibling(name='Hard Drives')
    <Category: Category: Hard Drives>
    
    get(node.pk).add_sibling(name='SSD')
    <Category: Category: SSD>
    
    get(node.pk).add_child(name='Desktop Memory')
```

In the above code if i want add child for sibling(ex:Hard Drives),how i can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the example: store objects in variables and use them. Have a look at **drives** variable below:

```bash
    >>> from fora.models import Category
    >>> get = lambda node_id: Category.objects.get(pk=node_id)
    >>> root = Category.add_root(name='Computer Hardware')
    >>> node = get(root.pk).add_child(name='Memory')
    >>> drives = get(node.pk).add_sibling(name='Hard Drives')
    >>> drives.add_child(name='HDD')
    <Category: Category object (4)>
    >>> drives.add_child(name='SDD')
    <Category: Category object (5)>
```